# Восстановление my.ini

Tags: mysql

Недавно удалил с помощью shift+del данный файл. Есть ли возможность восстановить его, может функция какая-либо?

MySQL версии 8.0

Comment: Здесь MySQL никаким боком. Это может произойти с любым файлом в системе. Качайте Recuva и пытайтесь восстановить. Чем меньше с диском возиться, тем больше шанс восстановить. Если же этот файл не имел никаких отличий от оригинала, то просто переустановить MySQL и всего делов.

Comment: А что там в нём было такого особенного-то? сервис прекрасно стартует и без этого файла, устанавливая все опции в значения по умолчанию. А если там было что-то нестандартно-критичное - ты просто обязан это знать.. создаёшь файл с нуля и пишешь в него всё, что требуется.

Comment: @void *Если же этот файл не имел никаких отличий от оригинала, то просто переустановить MySQL* Ну это явный перебор...